# Gnome-shell has no release candidate

Tags: gnome, 17.04, gnome-shell

I can't install gnome-shell on Ubuntu 17.04. What am I missing?

```
» sudo apt install gnome-shell                                                                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-shell is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-shell' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo apt update` to your post, please.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing some missing dependencies like:

```
apt install gir1.2-*
apt install gjs
apt install caribou
apt install gnome-backgrounds
```

Answer (score 0):

The package that you are looking for is `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`